# Porque tengo este error de conversión en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, stored-procedure

Hola resulta que tengo el siguiente error, y no se como hacer correctamente la conversión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo pienso que debe venir de esta, linea.

```
protected void DDL_FamiliaProducto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HddFamilia.Value = DDL_FamiliaProducto.SelectedValue;
    DDL_SubFamiliaProducto.Items.Clear();
    DDL_SubFamiliaProducto.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---SELECCIONE---"));


    //esta es la linea

    HDDSubFamilia.Value = DDL_SubFamiliaProducto.SelectedValue;
    DDL_MarcaProducto.Items.Clear();
    DDL_MarcaProducto.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("--SELECCIONE--"));       
}
```

¿Por qué será? Bueno claramente me lo esta tomando como nvarchar pero como hago la conversión correctamente.

Esto ademas viene de un procedimiento almacenado en donde tengo 2 variables declaradas como NVARCHAR() las cuales se comparan con unos campos de unas tablas que están en **INT**, pero si cambio el valor de esas variables a **INT** me arroja este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por eso pienso que debe ser aquella linea (Que indiqué con un comentario) eso.

Quedo atento a sus respuestas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La firma del método [Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/es/library/a2bk6xxw(v=vs.110).aspx) que estas usando es:

```
public void Insert(int index, ListItem item)
```

Por lo tanto, el 0 que estás agregando no es el valor sino el índice. Entonces después cuando usas ese item para mandarlo a la base falla porque no tiene un valor que se pueda convertir a `int`. Entonces podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
DDL_SubFamiliaProducto.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---SELECCIONE---", "0"));
```

Y setearle 0 como valor.

Comment: Probé eso pero me sigue arrojando el error

Comment: Deberías mostrarnos como estás armando el commando para el ListControl

Comment: Ya quedó lo revise y escribí mal aquello que me dijiste, ahora lo corregí y ya no arroja el error

Comment: +1 no sabía que al agregar items al DropDownList podías especificarle el `index`.